# mysql - I deleted the user table! how can I recover it?

Tags: mysql

I sure i deleted the table 'mysql' in an accident , then have maked this error "Table mysql.user dosen't exist"

How can i fix it , or create a new table 'mysql'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you did not just delete the table - you deleted the entire mysql permission database. 
You need to locate the script 'mysql_install_db'. This will recreate the mysql permissions database.

Be aware that by deleting and recreating the permission database - other applications may stop working because their users/etc no longer exist.

Comment: Good point on the applications. I forgot to add that in my answer

Comment: @James - thanks - only know this because I've hit this wall before ;-)

Comment: so I accidentally did this as well (was trying to migrate a DB and accidentally migrated it to itself...)  But my user was still able to login.  are users\passwords cached?

Answer (score 2):

There is not alot you can do. If you can run queries and have recently backed up the whole database using "BACKUP TABLE", then you can try to run this query:

```
 RESTORE TABLE mysql.user FROM '/path/to/backup/directory'
```

If you cannot then you will have to execute mysql with '--skip-grant-tables' option in the command line. This will allow you to atleast gain access. You can also recreate it by running the mysql_install_db command. [Found Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-install-db.html)

Either way your table should look like this

```
 +-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ 
 | Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra | 
 +-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ 
 | Host | varchar(20) | | PRI | | | 
 | User | varchar(6) | | PRI | | | 
 | Password | varchar(41) | | | | | 
 | Select_priv | enum('N','Y') | | | N | | 
 | Insert_priv | enum('N','Y') | | | N | | 
 | Update_priv | enum('N','Y') | | | N | | 
 | Delete_priv | enum('N','Y') | | | N | | 
 | Create_priv | enum('N','Y') | | | N | | 
 | Drop_priv | enum('N','Y') | | | N | | 
 | Reload_priv | enum('N','Y') | | | N | | 
 | Shutdown_priv | enum('N','Y') | | | N | | 
 | Process_priv | enum('N','Y') | | | N | | 
 | File_priv | enum('N','Y') | | | N | | 
 | Grant_priv | enum('N','Y') | | | N | | 
 | References_priv | enum('N','Y') | | | N | | 
 | Index_priv | enum('N','Y') | | | N | | 
 | Alter_priv | enum('N','Y') | | | N | | 
 +-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: By the way, how cant i delete a database called 'my/db', i use `drop database my/db` that will shows me error of syntax.

Comment: database names should (and normally cannot) contain \ or /. Normal naming conventions use CamelCase and _ for naming. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html - 8.2. Schema Object Names

Comment: But it has a table called `my/db` in there before i created, i just want to to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix by running a file mysql_upgrade found in mysql/bin directory.
Just run that file and it will fix all your tables.

Comment: Running mysql_update -uroot -v -f gives me: \bin>mysql_upgrade -u root --force
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1524: Plugin '*3341D225A70FDF32F7D6E158192BF9A65654BE7F' is not loaded while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.