# Unable to connect mysql in netbeans ide

Tags: mysql, netbeans-7, mysql-connector

I am using netbeans ide 7.1.2 and using mysql db with the necessary driver connector. By mistake i deleted the default table "user" in one of my database. Now i could not connect any of my database in netbeans. Whenever i connect it throws the following error.

**Unable to connect.Cannot establish to jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.15.:3306/mysql using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Communication link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets form the server).**

Comment: Can you connect to MySQL in other ways? Does the user as whom you connect exist? How are you trying to connect in Netbeans?

Comment: You didn't delete the table `user` out of the database `mysql`, did you?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this, it guides you how to restore the deleted table

[mysql - I deleted the user table! how can I recover it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816124/mysql-i-deleted-the-user-table-how-can-i-recover-it)

Comment: Hi all thank you!! i created a new one with different port now my db in netbeans works ...