# Accidentally deleted MySQL users

Tags: mysql, navicat

I accidentally deleted all users in MySQL including localhost. Now I can't even access my connections. How can I add localhost use to access my connections?

[image]

Comment: Can't do anything

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` is not a user, it's a special host, referring, well, to the local host. That means the host machine the software in question is running on.

So, when using a MySQL Client software like Navicat, `localhost` means that you want it to connect to a MySQL database that is running on the same machine as Navicat itself, instead of connecting over the network to a database running on some remote machine.

Now, regarding your question, if you deleted the `user` table (or its content) from the MySQL database running on your `localhost`, the only way I know of to bring the users back is restoring a backup of the database, if you have one.

You might be able to get access to the database again by recreating the `user` table using the [`mysql_install_db`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-install-db.html) script as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816124/mysql-i-deleted-the-user-table-how-can-i-recover-it), but this won't recover the previously existing users.

Comment: What if I do not have a back up? Is there any other way to get it back?

Comment: I updated my answer with a small addition in the last paragraph.

Comment: I can't even manage the users of MySql. Any the I can create a connection bu i can't access it. any other suggestions. i really need it. My system won't work any more. My PC is the server of the network.